# Why is volatile optional in multithreaded code?

Tags: c, multithreading, volatile

In miniaudio they used to add `volatile` to indicate that a variable can be changed by multiple threads but they removed it, change log "Add the MA_ATOMIC annotation for use with variables that should be used atomically and remove unnecessary volatile qualifiers."

They added a `#define MA_ATOMIC` that does nothing instead of using `volatile`. Why isn't the volatile qualifier necessary?

The repo: https://github.com/mackron/miniaudio

Comment: `volatile` is not so much *optional* as it is *insufficient*.  And if you put in measures that are sufficient, such as protecting access via a mutex or using an atomic object, then `volatile` doesn't provide anything useful on top.